# Django, creating variables in a Template and assigning a value

Tags: python, django, templates

I am trying to create a template in Django. In that template i have:
`dato` which contains a dictionary like this `{"Name":"Someone","Age":"23"}` and `propiedad` which contains a dictionary like this `{"parameterName":"Name"}`. I can make `{{propiedad.parameterName}}` and get the value `Name`. After that i would like to store that value in a `buffer`(which doesnt exist until now) order to do later `{{dato.buffer}}` obtaining `Someone` which i would show in the HTML. I don't know how to do this, can someone help me?

A fragment of the code:

```
 <tbody>
       {% for dato in atributo.datos %}
       <tr>
          {% for propiedad in atributo.propiedades %}
          <td>
            {# I would make the stuff here#}
            {{ dato.buffer}}
          </td>
          {% endfor %}
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using django filters. But we will have to code our own custom filter.

Include this in the views file

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register

@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

In the html file you can add the following line. We are passing the `dictionary` and `key` to `get_item` filter which returns the `value` of the key.

```
 <td>{{ dato|get_item:propiedad }}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you need to write your own custom [django template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) something like this:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
...
@register.filter
def getparam(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

and use this to get it in your html:

```
{{ dato|getparam:propiedad }}
```